# How should I spend my points and acquire gear?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm pretty sure there are plenty guides out there about Honor Points, but I want a very simple and short advice from an experienced player to who's looking for it the first time.

Should I just save honor points and buy stuff only when I get to level 80, or should I go and try to buff up on lower levels?

What about on level 70 - does it worth going BG all the way to gather HP and buff up the equips, both for leveling and for more fun at BGs all the way till 80?

How many points do we need on each level (starting at 79, then 69, 59, and so on) to have the best gear avaiable for PvP?

I think HP gear is only worth for PvP since the gear we get for PvE from doing PvE is already good enough.

Comment: I suggest editing the title into something that resembles your question such as: should I buy gear with honor points before level 80?

Comment: @Ivo but that's over simplifying it. Actually, people mostly missed my question into what you suggested.

Comment: Now there no question in THE title @Cawas

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned (if you have a lvl 80 main) the option of buying the heirloom pvp pieces. If you have an 80 main who can just farm stone keeper shards and honor, you will get sick of just spending honor on gems and re-selling them so pick up an heirloom pvp piece instead (from the WG vendor). Too bad the legacy vendors dont sell the lowbie gear as BOA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, questions has been asked many times.

Here is what you do while leveling:

Do Battlegrounds, as A) It gets you honour but B) It now gets you experience points for completing objectives which means your "killing 2 birds with one stone" as the expression goes.

**DO NOT** spend your Honour Points whatever you do. Wait until you get to level 80. Even when you get to level 80, do not spend them, as you wont have nearly enough for what you need.

Once you reach level 80, there are several things you need to do. Firstly I would suggest not going to BG as you will get destroyed. Instead doing your HC's and getting PvE gear. Once you have decent PvE gear, you can start doing things Like VoA which allows you to gain your PvP gear. Also with decent PvE gear you can half decently play PvP BG, although with no resilience you are bound go get done.

Once you have accumulated the Honour Points you need, start buying your PvP gear. First of, you want to get the set bonus that gives you 100+ resilience, this is two items. If you want to do PvP you need to get this quickly, therefore you need to get the cheapest two items, (normally shoulders and hands if I remember correctly). Once this is done you are good to keep adding, once you have your 100+ resi, you'll find it much easier to do PvP but not that wrathful gear is out, our still going to struggle.

Additionally what you want to do is gain Sons of Hodir reputation to allow you to get the head enchant for when you get your head.

REMEMBER: Always gem and enchant your itmes with the best you can possibly get as soon as possible.

Comment: This answer is so wrong, in so many ways. You can only accumulate 75K honor points, no more. Most of head, and shoulders enchants are gotten from reputation, get exalted with all WoTLK factions, it isn't difficult. Vibralux, read your answer again and fix things that do not make sense, and correct grammar and spellings, please.

Answer (score 7):

Don't buy anything with honor until level 80. The moment you hit 80 and step into a battleground your level 70 gear will pale in comparison to the PvP gear that everyone else has been accumulating over the past year. Save up and try to get the best level 80 gear and run VoA (Vault of Archavon) for additional PvP pieces.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on leveling straight to 80 it's not necessary to purchase honor gear along the way. Dungeons and quests will give you plenty of items. In fact, the dungeon gear will be good enough to make you a force to be reckoned with in BGs anyways. I would recommend saving your points until 80 so you can buy a few pieces right away.

Answer (score 1):

Some advice is not that good, IMO. I don’t agree with Vibralux.

Simply put. Do BGS all the way through leveling, save the honor, if you are capped (near 75k) but an 80 level piece and save it for later. Keep doing bgs.

When you get to 80, start queing for bgs. Random bgs. Over and over. If you do it all day long you’ll get most of your gear in a week.

Put the best gems+enchants and in about two weeks you can step into arenas.

Don’t worry about being destroyed, it helps you learn your class better. It’s not fun, but it doesn’t really last long. I did this with 6 chars and it always worked. ;)

Comment: I was going to do BGs anyway, but yeah, it really is not fun at all before lv x5, unless you have uber gear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you think the gear is only worth it for PvP (ie. not leveling), so then the question becomes do you want to PvP now? or at level 80?

The honor gain at level 80 is much higher so it is more efficient to level quickly and PvP at 80.  That said, many people enjoy PvP-ing at lower levels.

If you are only concerned with PvP at 80, then I would say, don't bother with PvP at all.  However, if PvP at other levels has intrinsic value to you, then spend the points and get the most value for your time (as saving them is largely meaningless compared with the increase in honor gain at 80).

Comment: well, I'm not saying it is only worth for PvP, I'm saying that Honor Points are hard to get and it's not worth to spend them on PvE gears. As far as I cant tell, at least.